# How do I turn gray and white pixels on black lineart into a transparent gradiant?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, transparency, gradient, line-art

I'm hoping my question is a simple one, as I'm strapped for time.
[image]

To put it simply, the lineart looks great from afar, and I plan on adding color to it in a layer under. But unfortunately, due to a bad tip, the lineart became filled with gray and white, covering up color and making it look horrid.

This can be fixed by turning these gray and white pixels into black and having them fade from the middle (The way most black brushes would look when used over a transparent background), but insofar I haven't found a way to do it. Even in most gradiant tutorials.

If I could get a step-by-step way to fix this, I'd be greatly appreciative.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the lines are in individual layer, the colors are on a separated layer underneath.
please follow the steps

1. choose the black and white layer from the layer panel
2. from the layer panel at the top select the color mode which is a usually a dropdown list labeled Normal as a default layer color mode. from this menu list choose "**Multiply**"
3. check the result on your file.

That's it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Alt+2 (CS4+) - selects the white, then Delete to remove it.

Comment: Please explain better what you mean, for example with adding a screenshot.